# How do I have a form "updated" by its "childform" when its clicked

Tags: c#, .net, forms, event-handling

So I got a basic game that has 2 windows one is the main game one is the settings menu they are both a subclass of Form however the eventhandler f2.MouseClick (the second form) Only ever triggers at the beginning and never ever works when I got Class 2 form open and move around with my mouse. Am I doing something wrong with the eventhandler?

```
Class1: Form{
public Class2 f2 = new Class2();

public class1(){
f2.MouseClick += Changesettings;
}





public {Some eventhandler for mouseclick}
}
Class2: Form{

}
```

Ive tried to link it to like paint and do it locally but none of them would trigger from the second form so I think it wont trigger at all as I dont know any other ways to trigger the Class 1 to update when clicked in a "subclass"  since you cant call on statics the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using an `eventhandler` in `ChildClass` and invoking it triggering the `ParentClass` action off `child.eventargs += trigger;`
With the following code:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public void ShowChildClass()
    {
        var child = new ChildClass();
        
        child.OnChildButtonClicked += ParentEventHandler;
        
        child.Show();
    }
    
    public void ParentEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invoked!");
    }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    public event EventHandler OnChildButtonClicked;
    
    public void Show() { }
    
    public void OnSomeKind_OfEvent()
    {
        OnChildButtonClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Copied the answer from my Reddit question by sjetware on r/csharp